Reading Polygon data from Teradata into Tableau
I understand Tableau can't read a clob field in Teradata where I have the Polygons. However I understand there is a work around to extract data that can be used by Mapping capabilities of Tableau. Can you please suggest in SQL or with any other function what format it is expecting the data to be so I can draw the shapes /map inside Tableau?
My CLOB data looks like this:
POLYGON((-xx.xxxxx xx.xxxxxx,-xx.xxxxx xx.xxxxxx,-xx.xxxxx xx.xxxxxx))


What have you tried so far?

I am able to split the lat and long and convert then to decimal numbers however Tableau is still very slow, it is able to render but for one state map it is taking 2 min or more

If you are able to read your CLOB field so that Tableau recognizes it as as having the datatype string, and if your text strings contain WKTF, then all you need to do is change the datatype in Tableau to spatial.
Then Tableau will recognize that field as having spatial geometry values. Then you can place your spatial field's bill on the detail shelf, and then the generated Latitude and Longitude fields will populate from the WKTF geometry, allowing you to display and perform calculations on spatial objects.
If your driver ignores CLOBs, you may be able to use Custom SQL to turn the CLOB into some form of text that Tableau can recognize.
